# Search Gtk# TreeModel using Foreach function

Tags: c#, gtk#

Could anyone provide a TreeModel.Foreach function example?.  I am having difficulty figuring out the syntax in c#.

Given an object I would like to search the tree to see if any of the TreeIters contain that object (I know which column to use).  The object may be one of three different types.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been asked a while ago but since I was looking for a solution to this very question I figured other people might as well.
So here's the correct syntax for the `ListStore.Foreach` (I assume the syntax will be the same for `TreeModel.Foreach`):

```
listStore.Foreach(new TreeModelForeachFunc(delegate(TreeModel model, TreePath path, TreeIter iter) {
    // Do whatever you want to do here...
}));
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: also worth noting that if the function returns true then iteration ceases, from the python documentation: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreemodel.html